# Dimensions of an object

Tags: dimensions

I need help to find/change the Dimensions of an object. I am currently working on a Minecraft server and to make a banner in Blender, I want to size a plane to 480x60. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @ItsDubs. You might want to take the [tour](http://www.blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and check out the [help center](http://www.blender.stackexchange.com/help). Your question is lacking some critical information that would enable people to answer in any detail, for example, you want your plane sized to 480 x 60 what? Blender units? Minecraft Units? kilometers? centimeters? What is the scale factor needed to convert one blender unit to one minecraft unit? (Continued)

Comment: (Continued) You might find that the video tutorial on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/oI7uhN8aYQg) contains useful information.

Answer (score 0):

just quick, you can open the n menu and change the dimensions there. then you go to scene settings menu and change the units to whatever you like

Comment: Is there an updated answer to this? `n` shows me many things, but not dimensions.